# How can I pull a MDI Child form out of the Parent MDI in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, parent-child, drag, mdi

I have a C# application which has a MDI Parent form and 2-3 child forms. Is it possible to pull out any child form out of the Parent form boundary? It would be helpful because a user can monitor all forms in a flexible way and would love to work on such application.

Comment: Read up on docking forms

Comment: Have you try anything?

Comment: You cannot "pull it out", that violates the MDI windowing model.  Setting the MdiParent property to *null* otherwise works well enough to get it to escape from the parent.